# Endomorphisms exercise explanation correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{Id}\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}$I have an exercise from an older exam I‘m trying to solve. But even with solutions I can‘t seem to be able to understand the way the proved them.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb {R}$-vector space, and let $f$ and $g$ be two endomorphisms of $V$ such that: $f \circ g = g \circ f = 0$

and $f + g = 2\id_V$

$(1)$ Show that $f \circ f = 2  f$

$(2)$ Show that $\im(f)=\ker(g)$

As I already mentioned, I have solutions to both exercises but they seem so short and maybe skipped some intermediate steps, which is why I don‘t really know how they go this far.

Is this "explanation" for $(1)$ correct?

Since $f \circ g = 0$ we have that $f \circ f = f \circ f + 0  = f \circ f + f \circ g =  f \circ(f+g) = 2f$

I‘m not sure why this is the case though, is it just because adding $0$ to $f \circ f$ doesn‘t change the outcome or am I missing something? Also the last step isn't really clear to me. Is
$f \circ(f+g) = 2f$ because of $f + g = 2\id_V$?

Also for $(2)$, I don‘t quite know how this follows from the definitions. I do have the solutions in front of me but I can't really follow it.

Comment: Your reasoning for (1) is correct. $f \circ (f +g) = f \circ (2 Id_V) = 2f$ holds because $f$ is linear.

Comment: For (2), try showing each is a subset of the other.

Comment: @bs_math That's what I thought, thanks! We know it's linear since it's an endomorphism right?

Comment: Yes, exactly (abcd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation for $1$ is correct. $f\circ (f+g)=2f\because f+g=2\mathrm{Id}\implies f\circ(f+g)=f\circ(2\mathrm{Id})=2f$. “Adding zero” is shorthand for adding the zero map (a linear operator that sends all inputs to zero) which would not affect the other linear map in the addition; in the same way that zero is an additive identity for numbers, a zero map is an additive identity for linear maps - in fact, functions can be considered as elements of a vector space, and you could consider this as adding the zero vector (and thus not changing anything). $(f+0)(v)=f(v)+0(v)=f(v),\,\forall v\in V$, so the addition is valid and $f=f+0$ - we use the fact that these are linear here.

As for $2$, if $g\circ f=0$, then $g(f(v))=0,\,\forall v\in V$, which means that $g(x)=0,\,\forall x\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$, which means...

And you can consider the kernel of $f$ too; $f\circ g=0\implies\ldots$?

EDIT:

Since this answer is accepted, any future viewers/learners should know that I showed only a partial proof of $2$. One must also show that $\ker g\subseteq\mathrm{Im}\,f$ to complete the proof. This has been done in another answer and in the comments below this post. Bonus: the kernel of $g$ is an eigenspace of $f$, and likewise the kernel of $f$ is an eigenspace of $g$, with eigenvalue $2$ for both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So since $g(x)=0,\,\forall x\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$ , we know that Im$(f) \subset$ ker$(g)$ , and therefore also Im$(g) \subset$ ker$(f)$ ? Does this suffice already since we know both are subsets of eachother or does this alone not hold?

Comment: To be fair, bs_math’s answer covers the other direction fairly well. @23408924. Because $x\in\ker g\implies (f+g)x=f(x)+g(x)=f(x)+0=f(x)$, $x\in\ker g\implies f(x)=(f+g)x=2x\implies f(x/2)=x\implies x\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$. Indeed, you could say that the kernel of $g$ is an *eigenspace* of $f$, with associated eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: @23408924 I see your comment on their post - $f(x/2)=x\implies x\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$ because it means there exists some $y=x/2$ such that $f(y)=x$, which by definition of image means $x$ is in the image of $f$.

Comment: @23408924 Also, a formatting tip: on your post I edited in the Image and Kernel and Id symbols: by default, `\ker` renders $\ker$, but you can also write: `\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}` and then whenever you type `\im` *anywhere in your post* it renders as $\operatorname{Im}$. You can also write `\mathrm{Id}`  to render it as math-y text, or use the (single use only) macro `\operatorname` to render some text as if it were an inbuilt function.

Comment: Ah I see so both are correct they are just two different ways of showing that.  But I guess both ways are the same right? Since by definition $f \circ g = g \circ f = 0$ that the other way round is just the same proof?

Ah I didn't know that thanks. I'll use that in the future

Comment: @23408924 Oh no - I didn’t actually prove the other direction. Please *don’t* use that in the future! $f\circ g=g\circ f=0$ does *not* imply that the kernel of $g$ is entirely the image of $f$; in my answer I neglected to mention what the other answer did, which is that we need the identity $f+g=2\rm Id$ to show that the image of $f$ is $\supseteq$ the kernel of $g$, and together with the other direction that means $\mathrm{im}\,f\subseteq\ker g,\,\ker g\subseteq\mathrm{im}\,f$, which implies $\ker g=\mathrm{im}\,f$

Comment: I meant the formatting tip :)

I see I misunderstood the first part. So if I have to face a similar question again, if I know that $x \in \ker g$ and I can solve the equality for $x$, we can conclude that $x \in \mathrm{Im} f$ ?

Comment: We can conclude that $x\in\mathrm{im}\,f\implies x\in\ker g$ and that $x\in\ker g\implies x\in\mathrm{im}\,f$ which altogether concludes that $\ker g=\mathrm{im}\,f$ by everything I have written in the comments and by the other answer @23408924

Comment: Alright thank you!

Comment: What is necessary to show that two sets are equal (here, showing that the kernel and image are equal) is this: $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ implies $A=B$. Alternatively you can show that $x\in A\implies x\in B$ and $x\in B\implies x\in A$, or very alternatively you can say $x\in A\iff x\in B$ but all these statements are equivalent. That’s what you need for future problems like this. If your question hadn’t provided the extra information that $f+g=2\rm Id$, then we wouldn’t be able to show equality. @23408924

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed proof of (2):

First, $g \circ f = 0$ implies that for every $x \in V$, $g(f(x)) = 0$. Therfore, $f(x) \in \mathrm{ker}(g)$ and we obtain $\mathrm{Im}(f) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(g)$.

For the other direction, use $f + g = 2 \mathrm{Id}_V$. If $x \in \mathrm{ker}(g)$ it is $f(x) = f(x) + g(x) = 2x$. Therfore, by linearity of $f$ we obtain $x = f({x \over 2})$. Thus, $x \in \mathrm{ker}(g)$ implies $x \in \mathrm{Im}(f)$ and this gives the other set inequality.

Comment: Thanks! Why exactly does $x \in$ ker$(g)$ imply $x \in$ Im$(f)$ from$ x = f(\frac{x}{2})$?

Comment: @23408924 It follows from the definition of image; you have found an element in the domain, namely $x/2$ such that this element is mapped to $x$, meaning $x$ is in the image.